# Cannot Boot Windows 10 from Grub after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am new to Linux and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop and I have windows 10 running already. However, when I choose to boot windows from grub, it goes into "Preparing Automatic Repair" and will fail afterwards. I can only boot Windows by Pressing F2 button after switching on desktop and go into BIOS to change boot order with "Windows Boot Manager" being the first. I want to know how I can fix this issue.

Below is the url of the report from Boot-Repair in Ubuntu. One thing I noticed is that the OS detected is on nvme0n1p4 but the grub menu I have for windows is on nvme0n1p2. If this is the issue, how should I fix this? If not, please let me know what is the issue behind this. Also, both systems were installed in UEFI mode.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R5w2wM4jTN/

Comment: You need to post the link to the summary report & remove the part of report you posted in question. You are missing a lot of info we need to see. You do have two ESP, but one per drive which is ok. But do not know which has entries in UEFI. You also show a bios_grub partition which means you tried to install grub in BIOS boot mode on gpt partitioned drive. Always boot in UEFI mode for both Windows & Ubuntu. Do you have good backups? Both Windows repair/recovery flash drive or installer with repair console & Ubuntu live installer?

Comment: @oldfred, sorry I am new to the forum and also all the terms about operating systems, I have a boot repair report in .txt format, how should I post that as a link? Also, I don't have backup for windows yet and Ubuntu is empty so I can easily reinstall it if needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you rerun report, it should pop up with the option to upload to pastebin site & give you a link to copy here. Do not run any autofix until reviewed by someone.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred thanks a lot, I have edited the question with the URL, please let me know if you find any issue from the report, thanks again!

Comment: Duplicate UUIDs & partUUIDs are not allowed. You have same UUID for the ESP - efi system partitions, `sda1      vfat     061A-B883 ` & 
`nvme0n1p2 vfat     061A-B883 `  Your Windows reserved is also the same as the Windows partition, do not think that is ok, but do not know Windows.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks so much, so how should I resolve this duplicated UUID issue? Is there any good thread online I could follow?

Comment: You need to change one or the other. `sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdaX` If you change sda1 then the NVMe ESP will be the ESP used for booting. Not sure then which you actually are booting from or maybe either will work. But best to have good backups and both a Windows repair/recovery drive in case you have to repair Windows to see correct ESP and Ubuntu live installer to reinstall grub if needed. Do not know Windows tools, but suggest you look for an answer on System Reserved on a Windows forum.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks so much!